# How to combine two function plots in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I can't seem to find a way to combine two ggplots having different function ranges.

```
library(ggplot2)
myfun <- function(x) {
 1/(1 + exp(-x))}

ggplot( NULL,aes(x)) + 
  stat_function(data=data.frame(x=c(0, 20)),fun=myfun, geom="line") + 
  stat_function(data=data.frame(x=c(10, 20)),fun=1/myfun, geom="line")
```

[image]

EDIT: Had a mistake in the question: `1/myfunc` instead of `myfunc` in the second function data.

Comment: What is the expected output that you want?  At the moment the two functions are being drawn on top of each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you want, but I give your function two different colors based on two ranges. You can use the following code:

```
library(ggplot2)
myfun <- function(x) {
  1/(1 + exp(-x))}

ggplot(NULL) + 
  stat_function(data= data.frame(x = c(0, 10)), aes(x, color = "blue"), fun=myfun, xlim = c(0,10)) +
  stat_function(data= data.frame(x = c(10, 20)), aes(x, color = "red"), fun=myfun, xlim = c(10,20)) +
  scale_color_manual(labels = c("blue", "red"), values = c("blue", "red"))
```

Output:

[image]

As you can see in the plot, the function is plotted within two different ranges.

## Answer to edited question

I would suggest to just make a second function like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
myfun1 <- function(x) {
  1/(1 + exp(-x))}

myfun2 <- function(x) {
  1/(1/(1 + exp(-x)))}

ggplot( NULL) + 
  stat_function(data=data.frame(x=c(0, 20)),fun=myfun1, geom="line") + 
  stat_function(data=data.frame(x=c(10, 20)),fun=myfun2, geom="line")
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: the thing is @Quinten, one line should start at 0 (the blue one), the other at 10 (the red one), on the x-axis. Both will peak at 20 (or 100%) on the y axis. That's how I understood the question

Comment: ahh i've spent the last half hour trying to have one line start at 0, and the other start at 10, as I saw ```x=c(0, 20))```, and ```x=c(10, 20))```in your question, meaning two different starting points on the x-axis (how I understood it).  Anyways, glad the other answer solved your problem.

Comment: @VADeR, I added code to your new question.

Comment: Thank you MR.@Quinten!! Sorry! I was pasting wrong comments while trying to fix my code. I wanted to plot two different functions with different ranges. This answer is what I wanted. I tried with ```ggplot(NULL, aes(x=x))``` and that didn't work for me. Could you explain why ggplot(NULL) works?

Comment: @VADeR, `NULL` is enough, because you want to plot two different functions with different ranges, which means with the aes(x=x) you will get stuck because of the two different functions you wan tot plot.